# How do i add more data into this array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am not very familiar with this type of array. How do i push another set of data in this type of array?

```
$array = array( 
    array(
        'service_name' => $row['application_name'], 
        'html_id' => $row['html_id'],
        'url' => $row['url'] 
    )
);
```

Comment: You might get a better answer if you expand your question to include what you want to accomplish. It seems that you are trying to move database data into array form, and there might be better ways of doing this.

Comment: @Bing ya thats what iam trying to do, grab data the DB and pushing it into a Array then sending the array to the template. Whats is the better way?

Comment: It depends on how your retreive your data, but I was thinking in lines of http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php and the comment from 23-Feb-2006 07:26. You can read it there, I won't provide an aditional answer here since you claimed that Greenisha's answer worked.

Comment: His answer did work. but your answer is exactly what i need. prior to your post i did something to that extend but this is a better example. Thank Bing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as far as I understood-

```
$array[]= array(
            'service_name' => $row['application_name'], 
            'html_id' => $row['html_id'],
            'url' => $row['url'] 
            );
```

will add another section, same as first

Comment: @M. of CA - this code will push it into the first array. Operator [] - pushes data into the end of array

Answer (score 2):

This adds another array to the outhermost array:

`$array[] = array('key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2');`

Answer (score 1):

Always take the path of the PHP man my friend :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 1):

it depends on which array you want to put data into :) - the first one is a [*classical array*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) and the included one is an [*associative array*](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31840&seqNum=3)

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on what the application or API is expecting but to take a wild stab at it, something like -

```
<?php

$array = array (
    array (
            'service_name' => $row['application_name'], 
            'html_id' => $row['html_id'],
            'url' => $row['url'] 
          ),
    array (
            'service_name' => 'app2',
            'html_id' => 'htmlid2',
            'url' => 'url2'
          )
        );
```